# Finding total number of states in a POMDP

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, pomdp

I've been working on a question that is posed in a document I've been reading, that models qualifying for a job as a POMDP. In this model, a person takes 3 exams, and must pass all of them in order to get the job. The person make either be qualified or not qualified in the subjects covered by each individual exam, and there is some probability that a person may be qualified for a subject covered in a particular exam, but still not pass (due to nerves). False passes are also possible as well.
A candidate is allowed a maximum of 2 exam attempts.

In understanding this problem, I've tried to list out all possible states the person might be in (qualified / not qualified for each exam), and have found the following possible states: (where Q is qualified, and N is not qualified)

QQQ
QQN
QNN
QNQ
NNN
NQN
NNQ
NQQ

So, the total number of possible states is 8.

Have I covered all possible states? I'm wondering if there's an easier way to find out total number of states, without having to list them all out in the above way. I'm very new to this field, so any help is appreciated.